php system() with single quote
I wish I could use rename() function in php; but I get "ERROR: Cross-device link" when trying to move a file/directory across mounted file systems.
So I rewrote code using system( "mv -i '$from' '$to'", $res);
This works fine when $from contains spaces; but when $from contains single quote; I get sh: no closing quote.
How best to resolve this issue? I reviewed the "similar questions" but they all relate to SQL.
